# Popup listView scroll and with imgaes

Tags: java, android

i want to create a popup with scroll listView and the listView will contain images,

i tried implement it with this code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View arg0) {



                      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(groupContext);

                    builder.setTitle("Group");
                    builder.setItems(arrayNames, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), arrayNames[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }

                    });

                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                              System.out.println("OK CLICKED");

                          }
                      });
                         builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                  dialog.dismiss();

                                }
                            });

                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                    alert.show();
                  }
            });
```

this code is working for me, however i cant add images and the listView is not scroll

thanks alot

Comment: I think the default Dialog's are too basic for what you want. I would try to make a Custom Dialog. That way, you have full control of what layout you show in the Dialog. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout

Comment: what u have tried regarding the listview with images?

Comment: use  "builder.setView()" concept.add listview to that builder like builder.setview(Listview instance);

Comment: builder.setview(Listview instance); it will show me only a listView? how can i add images to every listView item? thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a **custom dialog** with XML layout containing ListView.

Steps:

1. Define a XML layout with ListView
2. set XML layout inside dialog using below:

> ```
> dialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.this);
> dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_listView_layout);
> ```

Check this Simple example: [Android Custom Dialog Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

Comment: thanks alot, so do i need to create a listView with images add then to inflater.inflate it? thanks alot

Comment: @AdirRahamim no need to inflate it as we are setting view by using setContentView() method.

Comment: thanks alot, also do i need to use the method onCreateDialog as they used in this website: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout

Comment: @Adir Rahamim- not necessary...you can create your own method and can write code for custom dialog..!

Comment: @AdirRahamim Without making arguments, You should at least try to implement as the way suggested above, your all questions will be cleared automatically :)